# Edit adding in code that the author posted as an answer was rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, comments, not-an-answer

Yesterday, I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7832044) to a question. While I fixed up some grammar, the majority of the edit was pasting in the code that the asker had decided to put in an answer instead of editing it into his question. This edit was rejected because:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Should I refrain from adding the code when it's given in the future? My edit summary wasn't quite that clear. Rather than

> Fixed the English and added the code from his 'answer'

I could have written something like

> Fixed English; author added their code later as an answer so I'm putting that in the question instead

but at the time, the former seemed to be enough.

Was I right to edit the question?

Comment: I have no bloody idea what to tag this, so if anyone could let me know, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Your second version of that would have had a better chance at surviving I think. No guarantees though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Was I right to edit the question?

Yes. Your suggested edit was fine:

- it didn't change the original intent of the question
- it improved the content of the question
- it added additional information that the author has posted outside the question.

However, your edit summary suggested that you actually added an answer into the question. Also, even though *"how can i add "\n\t" between elements"* and *"How can I insert a tag on a new line with proper indentation?"* are semantically the same, the latter focuses on the insertion of the tag, whereas the first focuses on `"\n\t"`.

This probably lead to the rejection: a bunch of code of unknown origin (reviewers can't see the answer), and a changed question sentence. As Mat noted, a longer edit summary would have helped.

For the next time:

- make sure that your edit summary contains all information a possible reviewer needs,
- make sure that the original intend stays the same for a reviewer.

#### See also

- [Clarification for suggested edit rejection?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274449/clarification-for-suggested-edit-rejection?rq=1)
- [Suggested edit rejected, even though it follows suggested guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286991/suggested-edit-rejected-even-though-it-follows-suggested-guidelines?rq=1)

Comment: Of course it's quite possible the reviewer didn't even read the edit summary...